# Interacting with a Sandboxed PyPy interpreter - secondary .communicate() returns empty tuple

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

I'm trying to create a way to interact with a sandboxed PyPy interpreter from within a normal (non-sandboxed) cPython or PyPy script.

I've been able to compile a sandboxed PyPy interpreter following these instructions http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html and I have a pypy-c-sandbox file that works with pypy_interact.py to create an interactive sandboxed interpreter.

Now I want to do a very similar thing, but rather than use stdin/stdout as my io, I want to use a python script to interact with the pypy-sandbox process.  I've gotten this to work for the most part. I can use the .communicate() function with cStringIO objects as input, output and error and access this data from the normal python.

However, **and this is my issue**, when I call .communicate() a second time on the same instantiated PyPy sandbox object, I don't get anything back. It is as only the first .communicate works. I'm quite confused why this is the case and how to get around it.

I threw together an ugly hack to demonstrate my problem:

```
import sys, os
import autopath
from pypy.translator.sandbox.sandlib import SimpleIOSandboxedProc
from pypy.translator.sandbox.sandlib import VirtualizedSandboxedProc
from pypy.translator.sandbox.vfs import Dir, RealDir, RealFile
import pypy


LIB_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(pypy.__file__))

class PyPySandboxedProc(VirtualizedSandboxedProc, SimpleIOSandboxedProc):
    argv0 = '/bin/pypy-c'
    virtual_cwd = '/tmp'
    virtual_env = {}
    virtual_console_isatty = True
    arguments = ['../goal/pypy-c', '-u']

    def __init__(self, executable, arguments, tmpdir=None, debug=True):
        self.executable = executable = os.path.abspath(executable)
        self.tmpdir = tmpdir
        self.debug = debug
        super(PyPySandboxedProc, self).__init__([self.argv0] + arguments,
                                                executable=executable)

    def build_virtual_root(self):
        # build a virtual file system:
        # * can access its own executable
        # * can access the pure Python libraries
        # * can access the temporary usession directory as /tmp
        exclude = ['.pyc', '.pyo']
        if self.tmpdir is None:
            tmpdirnode = Dir({})
        else:
            tmpdirnode = RealDir(self.tmpdir, exclude=exclude)
        libroot = str(LIB_ROOT)

        return Dir({
            'bin': Dir({
                'pypy-c': RealFile(self.executable),
                'lib-python': RealDir(os.path.join(libroot, 'lib-python'),
                                      exclude=exclude),
                'lib_pypy': RealDir(os.path.join(libroot, 'lib_pypy'),
                                      exclude=exclude),
                }),
             'tmp': tmpdirnode,
             })

# run test
arguments = ['../goal/pypy-c', '-u']

sandproc = PyPySandboxedProc(arguments[0], arguments[1:],
                             tmpdir=None, debug=True)

#start the proc
code1 = "print 'started'\na = 5\nprint a"
code2 = "b = a\nprint b\nprint 'code 2 was run'"

output, error = sandproc.communicate(code1)
print "output: %s\n error: %s\n" % (output, error)

output, error = sandproc.communicate(code2)
print "output: %s\n error: %s\n" % (output, error)
```

I'd really like someway in which I can get `code2` to be run by the same sandproc instance but have it's input/output be returned separately. If I concatenate all of my code together and run it at once, it works, but parsing the output for a given input would be a bit of a pain.

Comment: communicate ends for the process to exit. Look how handle_until_return is implemented in sandlib to have an idea how to do it piece by piece.

Answer (score 2):

```
from rpython.translator.sandbox.sandlib import SimpleIOSandboxedProc
```

You are importing and extending SimpleIOSandboxedProc in PyPySandboxedProc. In the source ([sandlib.py source](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/rpython/translator/sandbox/sandlib.py)), you will see that sandproc.communicate() sends data and returns after the child process has terminated.

```
def communicate(self, input=None):
    """Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr,
    until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
    """
    import cStringIO
    if input:
        if isinstance(input, str):
            input = cStringIO.StringIO(input)
        self._input = input
    self._output = cStringIO.StringIO()
    self._error = cStringIO.StringIO()
    self.handle_forever()
    output = self._output.getvalue()
    self._output = None
    error = self._error.getvalue()
    self._error = None
    return (output, error)
```

In the above code, self.handle_forever() is called:

```
def handle_until_return(self):
    child_stdin  = self.popen.stdin
    child_stdout = self.popen.stdout
    if self.os_level_sandboxing and sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        # rationale: we wait until the child process started completely,
        # letting the C library do any system calls it wants for
        # initialization.  When the RPython code starts up, it quickly
        # does its first system call.  At this point we turn seccomp on.
        import select
        select.select([child_stdout], [], [])
        f = open('/proc/%d/seccomp' % self.popen.pid, 'w')
        print >> f, 1
        f.close()
    while True:
        try:
            fnname = read_message(child_stdout)
            args   = read_message(child_stdout)
        except EOFError, e:
            break
        if self.log and not self.is_spam(fnname, *args):
            self.log.call('%s(%s)' % (fnname,
                                 ', '.join([shortrepr(x) for x in args])))
        try:
            answer, resulttype = self.handle_message(fnname, *args)
        except Exception, e:
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            write_exception(child_stdin, e, tb)
            if self.log:
                if str(e):
                    self.log.exception('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
                else:
                    self.log.exception('%s' % (e.__class__.__name__,))
        else:
            if self.log and not self.is_spam(fnname, *args):
                self.log.result(shortrepr(answer))
            try:
                write_message(child_stdin, 0)  # error code - 0 for ok
                write_message(child_stdin, answer, resulttype)
                child_stdin.flush()
            except (IOError, OSError):
                # likely cause: subprocess is dead, child_stdin closed
                if self.poll() is not None:
                    break
                else:
                    raise
    returncode = self.wait()
    return returncode
```

As can be seen, the is a 'while True:', meaning this function will not return until we get an exception thrown at us. **So there is no way sandproc.communicate() will achieve what you would like it to achieve**.

You have two options.

The **hard option** is to fork your main process. Use one process to run sandproc.interact() with some os.pipes passed in. And use the other process to read from and write to the said pipes. This is inefficient as it requires 3 processes (one for the sandboxed application, one for the main process, and one for the forked process).

The **easy option** is to override some functions in the SimpleIOSandboxedProc class. All you have to do is reimplement these functions in PyPySandboxedProc.

```
def do_ll_os__ll_os_read(self, fd, size):
    if fd == 0:
        if self._input is None:
            return ""
        elif (getattr(self, 'virtual_console_isatty', False) or
              self._input.isatty()):
            # don't wait for all 'size' chars if reading from a tty,
            # to avoid blocking.  Instead, stop after reading a line.

            # For now, waiting at the interactive console is the
            # only time that counts as idle.
            self.enter_idle()
            try:
                inputdata = self._input.readline(size) #TODO: THIS IS WHERE YOU HANDLE READING FROM THE SANDBOXED PROCESS
            finally:
                self.leave_idle()
        else:
            inputdata = self._input.read(size)
        if self.inputlogfile is not None:
            self.inputlogfile.write(inputdata)
        return inputdata
    raise OSError("trying to read from fd %d" % (fd,))

def do_ll_os__ll_os_write(self, fd, data):
    if fd == 1:
        self._output.write(data) #TODO: THIS IS WHERE YOU WRITE TO THE SANDBOXED PROCESS
        return len(data)
    if fd == 2:
        self._error.write(data)
        return len(data)
    raise OSError("trying to write to fd %d" % (fd,))
```

The line annotated with the **#TODO:** label is where data is injected and read from the sandboxed process.

What you have to do is implement logic where you write some data (when the sandboxed process reads), wait for the response (until the process writes), write more data, and read the response again (when the process writes a second time).